# Problem when trying to launch the react native and expo app

Tags: react-native, expo

I am getting the following error when I am trying to start the react-native application in the android emulator.

ERROR  Invariant Violation: AsyncStorage has been removed from react-native core. It can now be installed and imported from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage' instead of 'react-native'. See https://github.com/react-native-async-storage/async-storage, js engine: hermes

ERROR  Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:

* Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.

* A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called., js engine: hermes

Comment: Are you using the AsyncStorage package directly? Are you using firebase?